How to publish angular library with images using webpack convert them into js files
When I use webpack5 convert images into base64
webpack.config.js
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png)$/i,
        type: 'asset/source',
      },
      {
        resourceQuery: /raw/,
        type: 'asset/source',
      },
    ],
  },

app.component.ts
 lazyloadFunc(name) {
    import(`./icons/${name}.svg?raw`).then((module) => {
      this.svgContent = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(module.default);
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }

It works on localhost, but when I use in other project I got some errors ;
errors
Package path  ./styles/icons is not exported from package ...
(see exports field in ... \package.json)

how to publish angular library with images?
